# How to use interfaces in custom control development?

Tags: sapui5

My task is to implement a list control, which should accept as `items` any control that implements specific methods, e.g `method1()` & `method2()`. I know this is possible because `sap.m.IconTabBar` has aggregation `items` of type `sap.m.IconTab` which is an interface.

No info exists in the docs however; I couldn't find the `sap.m.IconTab` definition in the github repo too.

The only thing I could find out is that the implementing control specifies a static object (similar to `metadata`) - `interfaces` where the implemented interfaces are listed.

How is the shape enforced on the implementor?

How is the `interface` registered with the framework?

How does an `interface` implementation look like?

Many thanks for any info on this in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some background**
Interfaces in UI5 started as pure tag (or marker) interfaces, without any content. That's why listing them in the `metadata` of the implementation seemed enough at that time (Example: https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.IconTab).

Later, interface requirements in control code evolved and they have been enriched with documentation(!) of their methods (Example: https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.cssgrid.IGridConfigurable or https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.Poolable).

**How is an interface defined (you didn't ask that, but for completeness):**

An interface is declared by writing a set of JSDoc comments. One for the interface itself, another one for each method or property in the interface.
(Example: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.layout/src/sap/ui/layout/library.js#L151-L179)

Restriction: Due to the pure documentation approach, interfaces cannot define managed settings (interfaces, aggregations, associations, events).

**How is the implementation of an interface declared?**

By listing it in the `metadata.interfaces` array.

**How is the shape enforced on the implementor?**

As interface are pure documentation, contract details cannot be checked at runtime. Internally, SAP internally uses a validation that, based on the documentation and code, compares interface declaration and implementation and reports mismatches. Unfortunately, this validation is not yet available outside.

**How is the interface registered with the framework?**

Only libs can declare interfaces and they list them in their `initLibrary` call. For the above example, the registration happens here: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.layout/src/sap/ui/layout/library.js#L56

**How does an interface implementation look like?**

1. add the interface name to the `metadata.interfaces` array
2. implement mandatory interface methods on the prototype of the
   implementing class
3. implement optional interface methods as needed
   (also on the prototype)

**How does TypeScript support for UI5 interfaces look like?**

The TypeScript generator for SAPUI5 transforms the documented interfaces to TypeScript interfaces. As TypeScript uses structural typing, not named types, we struggle a bit with our marker interfaces. As a workaround, we add mandatory properties to the interfaces and implement them (in the generated types) on both ends, interface declaration as well as implementation. This is quite ugly for consumers outside as they have to add those props as well.

Details can be found here: https://sap.github.io/ui5-typescript/beta-statement.html#what-kind-of-breaking-changes-are-currently-envisioned-and-hence-delaying-the-end-of-the-beta-phase-and-how-to-adapt-in-case-they-happen (search for marker interfaces).